# Reply-response pattern for primary-backup server

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

A backup server keeps sending keepAlive messages to the primary server. The primary server replies with the message 'Hey, I'm still running.'. If the reply has not come the backup server takes over the and starts a new message driven adapter.

1. How to implement this efficiently in Spring Integration?
2. How to start a message driven adapter from my code and NOT automatically by Spring ApplicationContext.

UPDATE: This is my current approach:

SENDER:

```
<si:inbound-channel-adapter id="keepAlivePoller" channel="keepAliveChannel" method="sendMessage" > 
    <bean class="com.keepAlive.KeepAliveSender"/>
    <si:poller fixed-rate="${keepalive.sendinterval}" max-messages-per-poll="1"></si:poller>
</si:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

and this is my receiver:

```
<si:channel id="pollKeepChannel">
    <si:queue/>
</si:channel>

<int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter id="keepAliveMessageAdapter" 
    channel="pollKeepChannel" destination="keepAlive" connection-factory="connectionFactory"  
    max-concurrent-consumers="2" auto-startup="true" acknowledge="transacted" extract-payload="true"/>

<si:service-activator id="keepAliveServiceActivator" input-channel="pollKeepChannel" ref="keepAliveService" method="process">
     <int:poller  />
</si:service-activator> 
<bean id="keepAliveService" class="com.keepAlive.KeepAliveService"/>

<bean id="keepAlive" 
    class="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue">
    <constructor-arg value="PREM_KEEPALIVE" />
</bean>
```

I would like to 1) somehow receive the reply from the sending server. 2) somewhow invoke the service (?) when the reply has NOT come.

Comment: though i have not worked in Spring integration but i can give general steps : Try to implement above requirement yourself but going thru spring docs available online and other examples. You can worry about efficiency/performance after you have something in place. And one tip have you considered using load balancers ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `auto-startup` to false; you can start/stop the adapter using its `Lifecycle` methods; you can either do that directly (by injecting it as a `Lifecycle`, or by sending a message to a `<control=bus/>` (e.g. `@keepAliveMessageAdapter.start()`.

You can keep state in some bean (each time you get a ping), and configure an `<inbound-channel-adapter/>` to poll a method on that bean that returns the control bus command to start/stop the adapter.